# How i can use some form elements and button click in amp html?

Tags: amp-html

I know AMP doesn't allow to use form elements in AMP html but if there is any hack or trick through which we can use some form elements or click events??Like any page including the **amp-iframe** If yes then explain with example please. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't directly right now, but support is coming: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/3343

If you are impatient, you can use `amp-iframe` as a workaround for now.